# Draw on a Pdf into a Window Form C# (visual studio 2015)

Tags: c#, winforms, pdf, pdfsharp, itextpdf

I'm a beginner of C#, so sorry if it's a dumb question.
I have to draw on a pdf that it's displayed into a WinForm of Visual Studio 2015.
When I click a point of the pdf I want to start drawing (isn't important what I want draw).
I've already the pdf into the form with Adobe Reader tool. But with some versions of Adobe Reader I can't draw on it or if the Pdf is protected I can use Adobe only to read it: I watched something of PdfSharp and Itext Pdf, but I'm not sure if it's possible to draw on a pdf with a mouse event.
If it's possible, how can I do it?

ps: sorry for the bad english :)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Can you add further details, the source code, and what you have done so far?

Comment: ok just +1 you because you will share your code :)

Comment: I've already put the pdf into the Windows Form, but now I'm blocked because I don't know how and if is possible to draw on the pdf into the form with a mouse event (I click into a part of pdf and I want that an arrow appear on my pdf. it's that possible?). I'v watched some online example of pdfsharp and iTextPdf and I haven't found nothing very helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Add PDF viewer control to ToolBox in Visual Studio. To do this, right click on the toolbox, select Choose Items... and in COM Components tab select "Adobe PDF Reader"

[image: Adding Adobe Reader reference to Visual Studio Project]

2) Place control on the screen by dragging it from ToolBox

3) In code, load the PDF file by setting the property src to file path.
E.g. pdfReader.src = @"C:\mypdf.pdf"

4) In run mode you'll be able to modify PDF just like in Adobe Reader by clicking on icon:

[image]

Comment: Thank you man, but I've already do this passage. Probably because of my bad english I didn't explain well my problem: I've already the pdf in the form, I want to draw something on it. With adobe reader I can only highlight some test, found a word or add a comment :)

Comment: I correct myself: I can draw with Adobe Reader, but not with all versions of Adobe (only the 10 and the 11). And if the document is protected I can't draw even with version 10 or 11! :/ There's a solution with PdfSharp or iTextPdf? (or something not from Adobe?)